# What is so terribly wrong with this code? It appears semantically correct to me

Tags: java, optimization

Saw in a blogpost that this kind of code drives the author insane.. Why?

```
public boolean foo() {
    boolean b = bar();
    if (b == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What blogpost? Anyway, `foo() { return bar(); }` is much better, although there's no semantic error in your code.

Comment: there's nothing wrong, it's just it is inefficient

Comment: @Codeek Multiple redundant statements are something wrong. It makes the code much more difficult to read.

Comment: hence inefficient :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there is a much shorter version of it:

```
public boolean foo() {
    return bar();
}
```

As others have noted, the whole function `foo` may be redundant. There are however situations where it cannot be eliminated, for example if it is defined in an interface you are implementing or if `bar` is private.

The construct `if (b == true)` is especially dangerous for inexperienced programmers, as it could be wrongly written as `if (b = true)`. This problem is not caught by the compiler but would silently always execute the true branch of the if.

Comment: @The111 not necessarily, for example if you have to implement an interface.

Answer (score 6):

Because it could be written as

```
public boolean foo() {
    return bar();
}
```

The code is unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 6):

Because the call to `foo()` (and the entire function itself) can be replaced with `bar()`.

Anytime you write:

```
if (something == true) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

All you're doing is returning the value of `something`, so why not just `return something;`?  And at that point in the code you provided in OP, the entire function has no point to exist since it's just returning the return value of another function.

Another similar use case (and equally annoying) is:

```
Foo foo = getFoo();
if (foo == null) {
  return null;
} else {
  return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

of all above answers, I think you don't even need to call foo().

just use

```
if(bar())
```

directly at the place where you are calling foo()

no need of `foo()` function at all

Comment: I think that foo() is merely there to put the annoying code into something.